# How do I limit auto completion results in JFXAutoCompletionPopup JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

```
    ArrayList<String> aniNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

I made connection with Database and stored 7K anime names in above ArrayList.

```
    JFXAutoCompletePopup<String> autoCompPop = new JFXAutoCompletePopup<>();
    for (int i=0; i<aniNames.size(); i++){
        autoCompPop.getSuggestions().addAll(aniNames.get(i));
    }
    autoCompPop.setSelectionHandler(event ->{
        autoTF.setText(event.getObject());
    });

    autoTF.textProperty().addListener(observable -> {
    autoCompPop.filter(string -> string.toLowerCase().contains(autoTF.getText().toLowerCase()));
    if (autoCompPop.getFilteredSuggestions().isEmpty() || autoTF.getText().isEmpty()) {
        autoCompPop.hide();
    } else {
        autoCompPop.show(autoTF);
    }
});
```

So I wrote this program in which when I type something, it shows auto completion popup.

When I type a single letter, lets say "a" or any other, It shows almost all anime having "a" in there names, which means almost all 7k anime.

I want to limit the number of results it shows if exceeds a certain number, for example, if more than 20 anime have "a" in their name then I want it to show only first 20 anime in the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
autoCompPop.filter(string -> string.toLowerCase().contains(autoTF.getText().toLowerCase()));
```

to:

```
autoCompPop.filter(string -> string.toLowerCase().startsWith(autoTF.getText().toLowerCase()));
```

might help you out, not by forceably limiting results, but by telling the popup to search for names that **start** with the entered text instead of names that **contain** the entered text, thus cutting down on the number of results.

It doesn't seem that JFXAutocompletePopup has a method for limiting search results, as setCellLimit() only limits the number of visible cells (essentially shortening the height of the popup and not the actual number of items).
[JFXAutocompletePopup source code](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/controls/JFXAutoCompletePopup.java)